# Making size of a 4x4 matrix that consist only 2 parameter of 2x2 matrix to be same size as 4x4 matrix

Tags: enumerate, matrices, multicol

From the picture below, both are supposed to be 4x4 matrices, but I want to express the first one with 2x2 matrix within 2x2 matrix where the J1 and J2 are 2x2 matrices while the 0 is 2x2 zero matrix. I wanted to make the size to look the same as this looks somehow ugly. Anyone has idea? I attached the code as well.

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $\begin{Bmatrix}
    J_1 & 0 \\
    0 & J_2 
    \end{Bmatrix}$
    \item $\begin{Bmatrix}
        \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & \lambda_0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_1
        \end{Bmatrix}$ 
    \item $\begin{Bmatrix}
            \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & \lambda_0 & 1 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_0
            \end{Bmatrix}$ 
    \item $\begin{Bmatrix}
            \alpha & \beta & 1 & 0 \\
            -\beta & \alpha & 0 & 1 \\
            0 & 0 & \alpha & \beta \\
            0 & 0 & -\beta & \alpha 
            \end{Bmatrix}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as _text_ not an image, preferably as a complete small document, so people can test their answers.

Comment: Can you teach me how to post it as code? >.<

Comment: Just cut and paste the text in to the question, then  highlight it and click the `{}` button in the editor (which just indents it by 4 spaces) the wiki then formats it as a scrollable text box

Comment: Better would be to have a full document `\documentclas....` so we don't have to guess where `Bmatrix` is defined. (I can guess but you never know) (I guessed wrongly about a `cases` environemnt today when someone didn't show their preamble and I assumed it was amsmath)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(5,-8){\boldmath\large$J_1 $}\end{picture}
&&
\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(5,-8){\boldmath\large$0$}\end{picture}
&\\
\phantom{\lambda_1}&
\phantom{\lambda_1}&
\phantom{\lambda_1}&
\phantom{\lambda_1}\\
\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(5,-8){\boldmath\large$0$}\end{picture}
 &&
\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(5,-8){\boldmath\large$J_2 $}\end{picture}
&\\
\phantom{0}
    \end{Bmatrix}$
    \item $\begin{Bmatrix}
        \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & \lambda_0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_1
        \end{Bmatrix}$ 
    \item $\begin{Bmatrix}
            \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & \lambda_0 & 1 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_0
            \end{Bmatrix}$ 
    \item $\begin{Bmatrix}
            \alpha & \beta & 1 & 0 \\
            -\beta & \alpha & 0 & 1 \\
            0 & 0 & \alpha & \beta \\
            0 & 0 & -\beta & \alpha 
            \end{Bmatrix}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option that just moves the 2x2 entries into a 4x4 position with an `\fbox` around them:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,multicol}

\newcommand{\pl}{\phantom{\lambda_0}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twotofour}[2][]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen@}{#1}%
  \ifdim\dimen@=\z@\settowidth{\dimen@}{#2}\fi%
  \makebox[0pt]{%
    \smash{\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}{%
      \setlength{\fboxsep}{2\fboxsep}%
        \fbox{\makebox[\dimen@]{\vphantom{#1}#2}}}\hspace*{4\arraycolsep}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item $\begin{Bmatrix}
        \pl & \pl & \pl & \pl \\
        & \twotofour{$J_1$} & & \twotofour[$J_1$]{0} \\
        & & & \\
        & \twotofour[$J_1$]{0} & & \twotofour{$J_2$} 
      \end{Bmatrix}$
    \item $\begin{Bmatrix}
        \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & \lambda_0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_1
      \end{Bmatrix}$ 
    \item $\begin{Bmatrix}
        \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & \lambda_0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_0
      \end{Bmatrix}$ 
    \item $\begin{Bmatrix}
        \alpha & \beta & 1 & 0 \\
        -\beta & \alpha & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & \alpha & \beta \\
        0 & 0 & -\beta & \alpha 
      \end{Bmatrix}$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

---

Another option with horizontal/vertical rules, defaulting to `array` for creating the first `Bmatrix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,multicol}
\newcommand{\pl}{\phantom{\lambda_0}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twotofour}[2][]{%
  \makebox[0pt]{%
    \smash{\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}{%
      #2}\hspace*{4\arraycolsep}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item $\left\{\begin{array}{@{}cc|cc@{}}
        \pl & \pl & \pl & \pl \\
        & \twotofour{$J_1$} & & \twotofour[$J_1$]{0} \\
        \hline
        & & & \\
        & \twotofour[$J_1$]{0} & & \twotofour{$J_2$} 
      \end{array}\right\}$
    \item $\begin{Bmatrix}
        \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & \lambda_0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_1
      \end{Bmatrix}$ 
    \item $\begin{Bmatrix}
        \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & \lambda_0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_0
      \end{Bmatrix}$ 
    \item $\begin{Bmatrix}
        \alpha & \beta & 1 & 0 \\
        -\beta & \alpha & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & \alpha & \beta \\
        0 & 0 & -\beta & \alpha 
      \end{Bmatrix}$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I use a TABstack.  For the three normal sized ones, the syntax was interchangeable, except for putting the environment contents into the `\braceMatrixstack` argument.  I did need to set up the horizontal intercolumn gap `2ex` in advance.

For the large matrix, I just made the letters `\LARGE` which took care of the vertical requirement.  I did need to add a little space to the left and right of the entries, and change the intercolumn gap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\setstacktabbedgap{3.3ex}
    \item $\LARGE\braceMatrixstack{
    ~J_1 & 0~ \\
    ~0 & J_2~ 
    }$
\setstacktabbedgap{2ex}
\setstackgap{L}{\baselineskip}
    \item $\braceMatrixstack{
        \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & \lambda_0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_1
        }$ 
    \item $\braceMatrixstack{
            \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
            0 & \lambda_0 & 1 & 0 \\
            0 & 0 & \lambda_0 & 1 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_0
            }$ 
    \item $\braceMatrixstack{
            \alpha & \beta & 1 & 0 \\
            -\beta & \alpha & 0 & 1 \\
            0 & 0 & \alpha & \beta \\
            0 & 0 & -\beta & \alpha 
            }$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]